# Mod rewrite ? being included

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

This is my rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule ^index\.php?(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My input url is `http://domain.com/test` but the browser is redirected to `http://www.domain.com/?/test` when I expect `http://www.domain.com/test`. [Tested here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

The idea is to redirect to `www.` but the problem is I'm using a custom framework which re-writes to `index.php?$1`.

Comment: Hi there!  Did the (updated) answer make sense?

Comment: I've only just seen your update, sorry. I'll test it and get back to you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Please see **UPDATE**, below.

Your problem may be that `?` is a regular expression metacharacter (like `.` and `*`):

> `?` means zero or one of the previous expression. "pin?e" will match both "pine" and "pie". [source](http://www.easymodrewrite.com/guide-regular-expressions)

Try escaping it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php\?(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Your existing rule is looking for `index.ph`, possibly followed by `p`, and then collecting all remaining characters into `$1` (which will include the `?`).

**UPDATE**

Upon review, I've made some pretty elementary mistakes here.  Allow me to correct them:

`mod_rewrite` only looks at the path portion of the URL...which means everything up to, but not including, the `?` separating the query string from the path.  So the rule I've listed above will never work, because the `?` and following text isn't seen by `RewriteRule`.

You *can* match against the query string with a `RewriteCond` directive, which gives us:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^/index.php http://www.domain.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

This dumps anything in the query string into `%1`, and then appends it to `http://www.domain.com/`...which almost works, but you'll find that a request like this:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?some/path
```

Becomes:

```
http://www.domain.com/some/path?some/path
```

We need to include the `?` in our rewritten path to tell `mod_rewrite` to erase the query string, which gives us:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^/index.php http://www.domain.com/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Using this configuration on my system, a request for:

```
http://localhost/index.php?some/path
```

Returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 31 Mar 2012 00:39:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.1 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.0g-fips mod_macro/1.2.1
Location: http://www.domain.com/some/path
```

Comment: I have already tried that, if you go to the link included and use your rewrite rule and the url as: `http://domain.com/index.php?/test/a` it does not remove the /? correctly.